# re-frame http event-fx that depends on data from another http event-fx

Tags: ajax, clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

Suppose I need widget data and widget parts data. I need to retrieve the widget data via http request to get its parts-numbers. I use those parts-numbers to make more http requests to get parts data.

Using https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx, it'd look like:

```
(reg-event-fx
 :foo/get-widget
 (fn [{:keys [db]} [_]]
   {:http-xhrio {:method :get
                 :uri "foobar.com/widget"
                 :format (ajax/transit-request-format)
                 :response-format (ajax/json-response-format)
                 :on-success [:foo/load-widget]
                 :on-failure [:foo/set-error]}}))

(reg-event-fx
 :foo/get-widget-part
 (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ part-number]]
   {:http-xhrio {:method :get
                 :uri (str "foobar.com/part/" part-number)
                 :format (ajax/transit-request-format)
                 :response-format (ajax/json-response-format)
                 :on-success [:foo/load-part]
                 :on-failure [:foo/set-error]}}))
```

How would I initialize my parts data for my page? The most straightforward method I can come up with is to wrap `get-widget` and `get-widget-part` by writing another handler `get-widget-then-widget-parts` by doing a http request for the widget and on success take that data and retrieve parts data. My issue with that is that it isn't very composable. I need to create another handler. At the same time I can't just `(dispatch [:foo/get-widget])` and feed the result into `(dispatch [:foo/get-widget-part])` (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your aim is to create multiple `get-widget-part` requests after `get-widget` returns the widget data with part ids. You could write an event handler that looks up the ids, and dispatches multiple `:foo/get-widget-part` events.

```
(reg-event-fx
    :foo/load-widget ;Your :on-success event
    (fn [{:keys [db]} [_ widget-data]]
      (let [ids         (get-part-ids widget-data)
            missing-ids (remove #(get-part-with-id db %) ids)] ;Load only missing parts
        {:db         (set-widget-data db widget-data)
         :dispatch-n (map (fn [id] [:foo/get-widget-part id]) missing-ids)})))
```

You likely don't want to fetch the parts "eagerly" every time. So, you could either A) provide a separate argument (e.g., `:fetch-eager`) and merge the `:dispatch-n` conditionally depending on that, or B) create separate events for lazy and eager fetching (say, `:foo/get-widget` and `:foo/get-widget-with-parts`). I would prefer the latter option B, as it easier to build upon, for example, when a dedicated API endpoint is added for fetching the widget with parts.

You can compose the creation of the effect map returned from the event handler. In the above example, lazy fetch action would create just a `:db` effect (e.g., `mk-db-widget-data`), while the eager version would be composed of both the `:db`update and the `:get-widget-part` events (e.g., `mk-dispatch-get-widget-parts`).